# Can't retrieve Principal in WebFlux Controller when using RxJava3Adapter to return a RxJava Single. Can you explain what's breaking the Reactor Chain?

Tags: java, rx-java, spring-webflux, project-reactor

My WebFlux controller:

```
import reactor.adapter.rxjava.RxJava3Adapter;
import reactor.core.publisher.Mono;
import io.reactivex.rxjava3.core.Single;

@RestController
@RequestMapping("/test")
public class MyController {

  @GetMapping("/mono")
  public Mono<String> getMono(ServerWebExchange exchange) {
    return exchange.getPrincipal()
      .map(principal -> principal.getName())
      .switchIfEmpty(Mono.just("no principal"));
  }

  @GetMapping("/single")
  public Single<String> getSingle(ServerWebExchange exchange) {
    return RxJava3Adapter.monoToSingle(exchange.getPrincipal()
      .map(principal -> principal.getName())
      .switchIfEmpty(Mono.just("no principal")));
  }

}
```

In the above code, `getMono` returns the Principal's name while `getSingle` returns "no principal".

I'm trying to understand why. It may have to do with the `RxJava3Adapter`. I'm not sure if it's turning the reactor publisher into a "hot" one because I feel like it's a race condition.

My Curl command (this fails)

```
curl --request GET \
--url http://localhost:8080/test/single \
--header 'authorization: Bearer XXXX' \
```

The easy solution is simply to convert all of our APIs to Reactor type but that is not an easy task. The RxJava type is strewn everywhere in our code, not just at the Controller. We would have to rewrite hundreds of files. So I'd like to understand this better before proposing going down that route.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I posted this question as an [issue](https://github.com/reactor/reactor-addons/issues/257) to the reactor github page. I found out that the reason the Principal is lost in the `Single` case is because we lose the Reactor Context when jumping to the RxJava chain, which has no concept of a Context. That Reactor Context holds the `SecurityContext` which has the `Principal`.
This is confirmed by the reactor team.